# MS Access - Conditional Formatting in Continuous Form on Specific Cells

Tags: ms-access, conditional-formatting, continuous-forms

I'm working on Access and I have a question to ask on conditional formatting. As you can see in the picture I have 2 columns of data, L/I and Unit Price.

What I want to do is whenever there is duplicated L/I appearing in the data, conditional formatting will

1. highlight the duplicated L/I, and
2. compare on only the specific unit prices with duplicated L/I and show the cheaper price with green
   font colour, yellow for price in the middle and red for the most expensive price.

I have done the first part as shown in the picture but I am clueless on the expression to be used for the second part. Not sure if I have articulated my concerns accurately but thanks in advance for attending to this question. Your help is sincerely appreciated.

***What my continuous form looks like:***

[image]

Comment: How you do that? Show here in post.

Comment: I expect this will involve calling a VBA custom function.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could set the record source of the form to a query like beneath that generates a 'helper'-column with the name *Indicator* that is filled with the text "RED", "YELLOW" or "GREEN" according to their unit price characteristic. Based on this column, inside the form you could use conditional formatting to actually show the unit price in the wanted color. Hope this query helps (you in the right direction). I assumed the table is called "Items", you should change that to your naming.

```
SELECT i.ID, i.LI, i.UnitPrice, iif(i.UnitPrice = (SELECT MAX(il.UnitPrice) FROM Items AS il WHERE il.LI = i.LI), "RED", iif(i.UnitPrice = (SELECT MIN(il.UnitPrice) FROM Items AS il WHERE il.LI = i.LI), "GREEN", "YELLOW" )) AS Indicator FROM Items as i;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. I am a noobie on this so I will need more time to digest this...but let me come back to you if I have any further questions. A bit complicated for me to understand now haha...Thanks again

Comment: Thanks again for @Tieme help. My edited code: `SELECT i.[L/I], i.Unit_Price, IIf(i.Unit_Price=(SELECT MAX(il.Unit_Price) FROM Retrieve_VQ AS il WHERE il.[L/I] = i.[L/I]),"RED",IIf(i.Unit_Price=(SELECT MIN(il.Unit_Price) FROM Retrieve_VQ AS il WHERE il.[L/I] = i.[L/I]),"GREEN","YELLOW")) AS [Price_Indicator]
FROM Retrieve_VQ AS i;`
But I got 2 problems, one is the query shows other unit_price without duplicated L/I as RED (thinking to put AND statement in expression builder). Another is [Price_Indicator]![Price_Indicator]=[RED] in table as doesn't work. Could you provide any further advise?